# Handling Relative position of datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I need help with the "rel" tag in datatables. I have a table whose first column contains an image and its last column contains a button, however if I need to add a new row with data, the jEditable requires me to map each field with a "rel" number, but I don't need a "rel" number for the first and last column, please how do I go about this? A few lines of the html is given below:

```
<thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>SiteID</th>
            <th>SiteRef</th>
            <th>SupplierID</th>
            <th>StartDate</th>
            <th>EndDate</th>
            <th>Voltage</th>
           <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
```

The form that adds new row of data to the table

```
 <form id="formAddNewRow" action="#" title="Add new supplier">
     <input type="hidden" name="ID" id="ID" value="DATAROWID"/>
     <input type="hidden" name="name" id="name" value ="" rel="0" />
            <label for="SiteID">Site ID</label><br />
        <input type="text" name="SiteID" id="SiteID" class="required" rel="1" />
            <br />
            <label for="SiteRef">Site Ref</label><br />
        <input type="text" name="SiteRef" id="SiteRef" rel="2" />
            <br />
            <label for="SupplierID">Supplier ID</label><br />
        <textarea name="SupplierID" id="SupplierID" rel="3"></textarea>
            <br />
               <label for="StartDate">Start Date</label><br />
        <textarea name="StartDate" id="StartDate" rel="4"></textarea>
            <br />
               <label for="EndDate">End Date</label><br />
        <textarea name="EndDate" id="EndDate" rel="5"></textarea>
            <br />
               <label for="voltage">Voltage</label><br />
        <textarea name="Voltage" id="Voltage" rel="6"></textarea>
            <br />

    </form>
```

The "aoColumns" for the datatable ajaxsource is given below

```
"aoColumns": [
            {

                "class":          'details-control',
                "orderable":      false,
                "mData":           null,
                "defaultContent": ""
            },
            { "mData": "SiteID" },
            { "mData": "SiteRef" },
            { "mData": "SupplierID" },
            { "mData": "StartDate" },
            { "mData": "EndDate" },
            { "mData": "Voltage" },
            {


                //"orderable":      false,
                "mData":           null,
                "defaultContent": '<input type=\"button\" id = \"selectLetter\" name=\"selectLetter\" value=\"select">'
            } 

            ]
```

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I'm sure this can be answered, but I'm too lazy to build a plunker or fiddle. I'll come back if you have one. But I guess you check out the mRender function for aoColumns instead of defaultContent.

Comment: Oh please come back and help me, I have a fiddle account, do you mean I should create it on my fiddle account? I will check the mRender function too. Thanks.

Comment: Yep, you should do that. This would attract other users who are willing to help too.

Comment: okay. Thanks. But in a situation where I have some js file on my machine, how do I do that in fiddle because fiddle won't actually implement what I need it to implement. Also I am getting my data from a database, so how do I do that in fiddle too?

Comment: That's why I'm too lazy to collect all the js for datatables, jEditable and to guess how your implementation might look alike. Just provide a minimalistic example of what you expect your code to do, mock up some hardcoded data, because ajax won't work so easily from a fiddle. Don't worry if your example does not work as expected, as long as you show some effort and spare others the guesswork  you'll be fine.

Comment: This is the jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/aadewojo/tQ4eQ/1/. Although not too comprehensive. but if you have a look at it i can explain better. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56955/discussion-between-kunbi-and-mainguy).

Comment: Hmm, that is a lot of unneeded functionality in your script. We surely don't need tabletools, jqueryui, validation etc to get this running. I will try to clean this up some more. Please add some links to your question which versions of makeditable and editable you are using. Also state the versions of dataTables and jQuery. As I understand it now, you want to show a detail form-row in which the user can change data of a clicked row, delete it. And where should the ADD Button go? Please add this info to your question or this thread might explode.

Comment: I didn't see this reply before you said you were going home. The version of makeEditable is 2.3.3 (jquery.dataTables.editable.js) and jeditable version 1.7.3. Datatable version 1.10.0 and jQuery version 1.10.1. When Add button is clicked it triggers the sADDURL and adds the data into a database. I am able to add the data to the database, but it doesn't show on the datatable until its refreshed.